# Form fields are not getting blank/reset when we click outside of the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

When we write something in the input field and then dont want to submit the form we click outside the form box but the form fields are not getting blank. I want them to get reset to the blank fields when open the form without refreshing the webpage.
Ps: The form is a popup form

Code for the form:

```js
$(function(){
$("#schedule-demo").validate({
    rules: {
      firstname: 'required',
      lastname: 'required',
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
      },
      phone : { required: true, minlength: 7 }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form, event) {
      submitInformationForm(form);
      event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="schedule-demo" hubspot-form-id="5bd0f54b-4329-40dd-973e-f1fedce07775">
  <p>Please provide us your contact information and the expert will reach out shortly.</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="demo-first-name">First Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="demo-first-name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="demo-last-name">Last Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="demo-last-name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="demo-email">Work Email *</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="demo-email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="demo-phone">Phone Number *</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="demo-phone">
  </div>

  <div class="button-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You would need to add some code for that, that's not a default functionality.

Comment: Try `$("#schedule-demo").trigger("reset");` before popup appers

Comment: @AswinKumar where exactly, I didn't get your point.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a js function that u can call with a button for example, and this resets all form inputs.

```
<button class="button" type="button" onclick="Reset();">Reset</button>

function Reset() {
    document.getElementById("schedule-demo").reset();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is I dont want to use a "reset" button anywhere in the form.

This is what I am trying and it's working but the error messages are still coming under input fields but all the fields are blank when I reopen.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> *"... we click outside the form box but the form fields are not getting blank."*

If you want to clear out the form when you click outside the form box, you could write an event handler that resets the form when you click outside of it.

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var container = $('#schedule-demo');
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $(container).validate().resetForm();
        $(container).get(0).reset();
    };
});
```

The `.resetForm()` is provided by the jQuery Validate plugin to reset all validation.  The `.get(0).reset()` will clear out the form's contents.

```js
$(function() {

  $("#schedule-demo").validate({
    rules: {
      firstname: 'required',
      lastname: 'required',
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
      },
      phone: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 7
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      // submitInformationForm(form);  // commented out for demo
      return false;
    }
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var container = $('#schedule-demo');
    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(container).validate().resetForm();
      $(container).get(0).reset();
    };
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<form id="schedule-demo" hubspot-form-id="5bd0f54b-4329-40dd-973e-f1fedce07775">
  <p>Please provide us your contact information and the expert will reach out shortly.</p>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="demo-first-name">First Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" id="demo-first-name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="demo-last-name">Last Name *</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control" id="demo-last-name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="demo-email">Work Email *</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="demo-email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="demo-phone">Phone Number *</label>
    <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control" id="demo-phone">
  </div>

  <div class="button-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
<button>click outside of container</button>
```

---

As a side note...

```
submitHandler: function(form, event) {
    submitInformationForm(form);
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
```

Using `preventDefault()` inside of your `submitHandler` function is completely pointless as the plugin developer does not provide a default `event` to prevent.

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    submitInformationForm(form);
    return false;
}
```